# Inspection Warning: Cannot find declaration for field

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Noob question. I ran RubyMine's Code Inspect on a file containing this class.

```
class Square
  attr_accessor :width

  def area
    @width * @width
  end
end
```

I was surprised to get two warnings on the line `@width * @width`:

`Cannot find declaration for field '@width'`

The [attr section of the Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#attr_family) wasn't helpful to me. Why is this a warning?

----Edit----
[Ruby-Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) says this about `attr-accessor`

> Defines a named attribute for this module, where the name is *symbol*.`id2name`, creating an instance variable (`@name`) and a corresponding access method to read it. Also creates a method called `name=` to set the attribute. String arguments are converted to symbols.

To me, "Defines" means it has a "declaration". The warning message doesn't make sense. "Warning: Field may not be initialized before use" is more accurate.

I think this is a RubyMine issue (if it is an issue at all). [RubyMine apparently uses its own code inspection protocol](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/code-inspection.html) and doesn't use a standard Linter.

Answer (score 6):

RubyMine's display of this warning in this situation is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13631).

Comment: Seems to be known since May 2013. It might help if we vote / comment on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `@width` is not being initialized.

```
class Square
  attr_accessor :width

  def initialize(width)
    @width = width
  end

  def area
    @width * @width
  end
end

x = Square.new(4)
#=> #<Square:0x00000002371ef8 @width=4>
x.area
#=> 16
```

Without that you would get an error when calling `Square.new.area` (as the square has been defined without a width being set).

Comment: Agree about initialization. But it seems to me `attr_accessor :width` is a declaration.

Comment: ``attr_accessor`` is a shortcut to two methods that set and get width. (``def width; @width; end`` and ``def width=(width); @width = width; end``). However, on the very first read (without writing to it) it will be nil which is why I think Rubymine is returning an error (I've never used Rubymine so can't comment on the error exactly). I would presume it's not viewed as a declaration as they're not variables but methods.

Comment: I'm looking in ruby-doc.com for the official info, then I will try to figure out if RubyMine is using a Linter such as `rubocop`.